# Sublime Text Repl: ML. use file.sml giving io exception

Tags: sublimetext3, sml, read-eval-print-loop

I am sure that this is a really basic question, but sometimes I can use "xxx.sml" in the Sublime SML Repl, and sometimes it fails with an IO error, not being able to open the sml file.

it appears as though it is not finding the path to the file, but I cannot work out the pattern, sometimes it works, and sometimes not.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the Sublime SML Repl". Can you clarify? Maybe with a link or two?

Comment: REPL http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
and using the Standard ML language

Comment: That sounds like something very specific to your particular set-up. All I can think to suggest is to post a list of the particular file paths that you've seen fail (and ones that work). You might also consider filing a bug with the SublimeREPL people.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load a program using `use "a.sml"`, the file `a.sml` must be in your current directory of SML process. You can use `OS.FileSys.getDir();` to check the current directory and `OS.FileSys.chDir("...");` to change it.